# How to pass value through instance?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript. How do I pass values to a function through an instance?

I have a few values in this object/instance that I want to pass to the main function (class), some of these values are optional, if not passed, default values will be used.

```
var test = new Test({
    buttonId: 'sb',
    inputField: 'saveTextarea'
});
```

Here is the function

```
(function() {

var buttonId, inputField, requestFileName, fileName;

buttonId = null;
inputField = null;
requestFileName = null;
fileName = null;

// constructor
this.Test = function() {

    // defaults
    var defaults = {
        buttonId: "",
        inputField: "",
        requestFileName: false, //if true, prompt for fileName
        fileName: Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
    }

    // extend defaults
    if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] === "object") {
      this.options = extendDefaults(defaults, arguments[0]);
    }

}



document.getElementById(buttonId).onclick = function() {

    if (requestFileName == true)
    {
        fileName = prompt("Enter file name");
    }

    var myTextArea = document.getElementById(inputField).value
    myTextArea.innerHTML = fileName;
};

function extendDefaults(source, properties) {
    var property;
    for (property in properties) {
        if (properties.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        source[property] = properties[property];
        }
    }
    return source;
}

}());
```

The logic is to simply display the fileName in the specified input field when the specified button is clicked, if requestFileName is set to true, then it will display the prompted name, if not it will use a random string which is the default.

But I am getting null for buttonId... can I get advice on this?

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pleasega/y62h4by5/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in Javascript `this` is kind of tricky.

First, you defined your variables within your function: `var buttonId, inputField, requestFileName, fileName;`

And then it *looks* like you're trying to redefining it by saying `this.buttonId = null;`

However `this`, at this point refers to the `window` object, not your function. So what you've essentially done is create 2 variables for `buttonId`-one that belongs to the `window` object and one that belongs within the scope of your function.

So when you come down and `document.getElementById(buttonId)`, `buttonId` at this point is `undefined`, not `null`.

You can verify this by putting in some debugging statements after declaration to see what they produce:

```
var buttonId, inputField, requestFileName, fileName;
    console.log(buttonId); // undefined

    this.buttonId = null;
    this.inputField = null;
    this.requestFileName = null;
    this.fileName = null;

    console.log(buttonId); // still undefined
    console.log(this.buttonId); // null
```

If you want to attach an event listener, you probably need to define properly what you what `buttonId` to be.

Comment: Hi, I understand I am getting a null but I am not sure how to solve that, if I don't use `this`, I still get the same result which I thought it would be getting the variables from default if not the instance if specified? How do I achieve that?